# How to show full WebStorm information in event log window of IntelliJ?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, eslint, prettier

I have a git pre-commit, like this

```
{
  "gitHooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,less,md,json}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.ts?(x)": [
      "prettier --parser=typescript --write"
    ]
  }
}
```

Sometime I will get errors when run git commit, like this:

[image: errors]

I want to see full information, so I clicked the "show balloon" link

[image: show balloon link]

now I get full information, but IDEA not formatting the full information, It's very difficult to read...

[image: not formatting information]

Is there a way to show full information and formatting to read?

Comment: Screenshots of text are not very helpful, please just copy the text output and edit it into your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regrettably, there is no option beside "Show balloon" to see full information.

It's a known issue, please vote for feature request here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156267